# Im an EFFIN newb to website building. Scripts are like flying a space shuttle

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting

I don't know the proper terminology to find my answer.  It's a jQuery/JS/script problem though.

Probably pretty easy to solve also -

How do I go about implementing a script, any script, in my .html files?

1) I like the idea of not slowing the page down, so I always inserted script right before the /body tag

2) Inside the  tag: I don't understand the library link thing.  What link goes in the head tag?

3) What else do I not know about implementing scripts? (is implement even the right verb to use when searching for JS answers?)

Thanks in advance for all the help anyone can provide.

PS - I'll be happy to reformat this question if it's way to broad and general.  Not sure if it stayed on topic, and I don't wanna piss the website off :)

Comment: Try learn.jquery.com for jQuery stuff and codecademy.com for JavaScript.

Comment: I've already realized my first potential mistake.

In the "<script></script>" tags, I never specified "text/xxxxx".

Comment: If you're using the HTML5 DOCTYPE (<!DOCTYPE html>) you do not have to specify that attribute.

Comment: OK.  I am.  And CSS3.  And testing everything in the top 4 Browsers as  per W3Schools.

I really didn't expect to much help so fast.

Comment: That is what SO is for - but in the future you'll want to be asking much more specific questions, supplying the code that you have tried.

Comment: I don't have any code at the moment.  The page I just built was a Henry Ford job.  I didn't want the visitors to be turned away by a slow load time, so for that one I opted on just getting from point A to B without heated seats and a moon roof.  Now that I know some basics, I'm "smart enough" to be dangerous.  I'll keep the specificity in mind next time though, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking out [Javascript basics](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3586411/JavaScript-Basics-Part-1.htm)

Comment: I'm going to.  I didn't think to Google those terms...  Too easy.

Comment: It won't let me click the check just yet...  I already had HTMLGoodies bookmarked.  My question is just so basic I really didn't think any website would devote time to "pre-answer" it.  Thanks to you also, sir/ma'am.

Answer (score 0):

1) You include any needed library of JavaScript before any method use in script.
2) You write your script logic between `<script>` tag (or in separate file).
3) You debug script.

It's good practice to put JS code at the end of html file, while css is in header.

Comment: Thanks, too keep from cluttering this up, I'm going to check the link below first, but BIG THANKS for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're interested in learning Javascript. Try looking for some good tutorial, I recommend [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/).

There you will learn all the basics, including how to write Javascript in your HTML, how to use external files, what are the uses of Javascript, etc. There even some more advance tutorials and tutorials for other languages. Check it out.